# Check if null Boolean is true results in exception

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
Boolean bool = null;

try 
{
    if (bool)
    {
        //DoSomething
    }                   
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());             
}
```

Why does my check up on the Boolean variable "bool" result in an exception?
Shouldn't it just jump right past the if statement when it "sees" that it isn't true?
**When I remove the if statement or check up on if it's NOT null, the exception goes away.**

Comment: The answers above about object unboxing are all correct.  
For completeness sake, however, you could also change your code to use the primitive "boolean" instead of the object wrapper "Boolean".  You should also refresh yourself on the difference between a primitive and an Object.

Comment: Meanwhile... `if (bool == Boolean.TRUE)` evaluates false without generating an exception.  Not sure if this was intentional in the case I just found.

Comment: @simon.watts that would be false for `bool` being `null` OR if `Boolean` was constructed explicitly (and not as reference to `Boolean.TRUE`). So not recommended; as opposed to `if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(bool))` which would work as expected, including safely handling `null` value.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

When you have a `boolean` it can be either `true` or `false`. Yet when you have a `Boolean` it can be either `Boolean.TRUE`, `Boolean.FALSE` or `null` as any other object.

In your particular case, your `Boolean` is `null` and the `if` statement triggers an implicit conversion to `boolean` that produces the `NullPointerException`. You may need instead:

```
if(bool != null && bool) { ... }
```

Comment: Technically a `Boolean` can be any number of true instances, not just `Boolean.TRUE`. For example `new Boolean(true)`.

Comment: I struggle to understand why `if (myBoolean)` (where `myBoolean` is `Boolean`) does not raise a compiler error or at least a warning. This is a gotcha for sure.

Comment: @JoshM. This is because Java does _Boxing_ and _Unboxing_ of wrappers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: @Vinicius sure, but the compiler should either do the null for us in this case, out through a compiler warning at least.

Comment: android studio is not accepting 'bool != null'

Answer (score 582):

If you don't like extra null checks:

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value)) {...}
```

Comment: @AvrDragon: does equals required  ?  Operator == works here since Boolean has only two values

Comment: @Atul Yes, equals is required here. Because (new Boolean(true) == new Boolean(true)) is.... false. Reason: Boolean is just an class and can have multiple instances as any other class in java.

Comment: yeah, that's a shame, the constructor should be private so it's ensured that it's a twingleton...

Comment: This is exactly what  Apache BooleanUtils' `BooleanUtils.isTrue( bool );` does.

Comment: There's absolutely no point in using Apache BooleanUtils over this idiom.

Comment: We can not really ignore null check here. Reason being if you add else block it will go to else for both null and false value.

Comment: If I think about it a little bit: it is just a particular case of yoda notation.

Comment: @AnuragSharma that might be what you want

Comment: @StaxMan someone must believed it's valuable if they added such an util ;d

Comment: @Line you may be too charitable in your assessment :)

Comment: @StaxMan no, actually it really was my case :)

Answer (score 113):

**Use the [Apache BooleanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html).**

*(If peak performance is the most important priority in your project then look at one of the other answers for a native solution that doesn't require including an external library.)*

Don't reinvent the wheel. Leverage what's already been built and use `isTrue()`:

```
BooleanUtils.isTrue( bool );
```

Checks if a `Boolean` value is true, handling `null` by returning `false`.

*If you're not limited to the libraries you're "allowed" to include, there are a bunch of great helper functions for all sorts of use-cases, including `Booleans` and `Strings`. I suggest you peruse the various Apache libraries and see what they already offer.*

Comment: Reinventing the wheel doesn't seem so bad when the alternative is using an external library for something as basic as this.

Comment: @PaulManta I agree if this is the only thing you'd *ever* use in the Apache Utils libraries, but the suggested idea is to "peruse" the libraries to expose yourself to other helpful functions.

Comment: There is a performance penalty for using these libraries. So for such basic things which are part of the language, you should not use libraries.

Comment: @Vlad Like I wrote to PaulManta, I agree, if this is the **only** thing you are going to use this library for then it's not worth the performance and "bloat" hit but often times it'll expose you to other helper functions that you can use, which makes the inclusion worth the weight.

Comment: @Josh Pinter it is not only about the weight of the inclusion, but also the overhead of calling that utility function. There is a space and time penalty for that.

Comment: *That* library is reinventing the wheel. I attempt to avoid such libraries as much as possible.

Comment: @mschonaker If Apache BooleanUtils is reinventing the wheel, what is the _original_ wheel? The idea is to avoid creating a bunch of helper functions that mimic what's already been done in libraries such as this. I also use `toStringYesNo` from this library in all of my applications.

Comment: Including an an entire library to get that functionality is not the right thing.

Comment: Wouldn't the original wheel be `Boolean.TRUE.equals(bool)`? There are definitely some useful methods in `BooleanUtils`, but you don't need it for this.

Comment: @nnnnnn Definitely don't _need_ it for this. Just another option. And an intro to Apache's utility libraries for those that are uninitiated.

Comment: The BooleanUtils code says: `return bool.booleanValue() ? true : false;` Isn't that redundant? Is it for better readability?

Comment: Coming back to my answer 6 years later and I still like this. **But** be careful with `BooleanUtils.isFalse( bool )`. When `bool` is `null` it will return `false`, which may not be what you were expecting.

Comment: How absurd is the type system in java when we need a library to tell if a boolean is false...

Answer (score 40):

Or with the power of Java 8 Optional, you also can do such trick:

```
Optional.ofNullable(boolValue).orElse(false)
```

:)

Comment: This answer should get more recognition, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 18):

`Boolean` types can be `null`. You need to do a `null` check as you have set it to `null`.

```
if (bool != null && bool)
{
  //DoSomething
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Objects.equals()

There is nothing wrong with the accepted answer by K-ballo. If you prefer a single simple condition and like me you don’t like Yoda conditions, since java 1.7 the answer is

```
    if (Objects.equals(bool, true)) {
```

or if at the same time you prefer to be really explicit

```
    if (Objects.equals(bool, Boolean.TRUE)) {
```

### Or better: avoid the issue

It’s not recommended to use `Boolean` objects thereby allowing a `Boolean` reference to be `null` in the first place. The risk of a `NullPointerException` like the one you saw is too great. If you need a kind of tri-state logic, it’s better to define an enum with three values. For example

```
enum MyTristateBoolean { FALSE, DONT_KNOW, TRUE }
```

Now we don’t need `null` at all. The middle constant should probably be named `UNKNOWN`, `UNDEFINED`, `NOT_EXISTING` or something else depending on your exact situation. You may even name it `NULL` if appropriate. Now depending on taste your comparison becomes one of the following two.

```
    if (myBool.equals(MyTristateBoolean.TRUE)) {

    if (myBool == MyTristateBoolean.TRUE) {
```

The latter works since the compiler guarantees that you will only have one instance of each enum constant. As most of you know `==` doesn’t work for comparing objects of non-enum type for equality.

Comment: I highly recommend this answer. This a great answer, following best practices.

Answer (score 2):

`if (bool)` will be compiled to [`if (bool.booleanValue())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue()) aka unboxing and that would throw a `NullPointerException` if `bool` is `null`.

Other solutions for nullable boxed Boolean evaluation:

- JDK 9+ [requireNonNullElse(obj, defaultObj)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-)

  ```
  import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse;

  if (requireNonNullElse(bool, false)) {
      // DoSomething
  ```
- Google Guava 18+ [firstNonNull(first, second)](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.guava/guava/18.0/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T))

  ```
  import static com.google.common.base.MoreObjects.firstNonNull;

  if (firstNonNull(bool, false)) {
      // DoSomething
  ```

`false` is used as the default for the null-case here.

Answer (score 1):

as your variable bool is pointing to a null, you will always get a NullPointerException, you need to initialize the variable first somewhere with a not null value, and then modify it.

Comment: If it were just that, the `catch` block would handle the NullPointerException. The problem here is that the OP attempts to unbox a null-reference into a primitive.

Comment: *"you will always"* - Not always, except for the sample, simplified code that doesn't do anything in between initialising the variable to `null` and then testing it. Presumably real code wouldn't be that simple or the entire `if` test could be removed.