# Is null == false in Java?

Tags: java

Does the following expression evaluate to true or false in Java?

```
null == false
```

I can't find any information about this on the internet.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005286/check-if-null-boolean-is-true-results-in-exception) is about wrapped `Boolean` value, and not about primitive `boolean`/`true`/`false`.

Comment: Not to be rude, but have you tried evaluating it to find out?

Comment: You can't compare `null` to a `boolean`. They are different types one indicating  a *null reference pointer* and the other a false/not true value. Thus the answer is: No this expression is not even valid (and if it was, it would be false).

Comment: @WaiHaLee It will be much easier for people to find out the answer by searching google and finding this, rather than starting up their IDE and creating new project just to find the answer to this simple question.

Comment: Why fire an IDE at all? Write a simple program by hand and try and compile it (hint: it doesn't)

Comment: @GiantTree Ok, write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It is so easy to find the answer by trying. Why bother searching on the Internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare `null` to a `boolean`.
They are different types one indicating a *null reference pointer* and the other one a *false/not true* value.

Thus the answer is: No this expression is not even valid and if it was, it would be false.

Comment: Besides that comparing null with false, throws null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

The `null` key word presents a pointer which point... nowhere. Which means Java can't get the value in the memory by it's index.

A `boolean` is a memory value of 1 bit, 0 is false and 1 is true (or inverse). The value is get with the **pointing index** of the variable (if this boolean is stock in such a variable)

You **can't check** an equality between something representing nothing and a one bit value.
Your line will throw an error !

*Before ask, you should try this out yourself !*

Answer (score 0):

null and false is not comparable

Answer (score 0):

it gives The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) null, boolean error

you can compare false == false or null == null;