# Java Boolean Class Variable Used in Comparisons

Tags: java

I have

```
Boolean condition;

public Boolean isCondition() { return condition; }
```

Is the following usage of this method then allowed, as with a primitive,

```
if (isCondition())
{
  //...
}
```

I would use that for primitives but not sure about the class. Does it need to be checked for NULLs? Do I need to getBooleanValue() first?

Comment: You can do this, but as You sad you have to check for null. Better use simple type.

Comment: Since `Boolean` is a class, it can be null. You can return a `boolean`, since it will be [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Thanks Turing85. You probably meant, you can return a Boolean (capital-B), because it will be autoboxed to a boolean (lower-case).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005286/check-if-null-boolean-is-true-results-in-exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use any boxed primitive (in your case, `Boolean`) as a primitive itself; namely, your example would work if you could guarantee that `condition` was set to a non-null value.

The caveat here is that if any of the boxed primitives themselves are `null`, [you will get a `NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) when unboxing them.  If you have the possibility of that value being `null`, you should re-evaluate why you're using the boxed primitive in the first place.  It may be better to use the unboxed primitive (in your case, `boolean`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it needs to be checked against `null` since it is a reference type. The automatic unboxing to the primitive type `boolean`, which is done in the `if` condition, relies on calling `Boolean#booleanValue()` which would throw a NPE in case the `condition` variable is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution,

```
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(isCondition()) ){ .. }
```

This will never throw an NPE because the expression is on the right-hand side, and we can still compare it.