# Why Boolean null object gives me null pointer exception but String do not give me NPE while comparing using == operator

Tags: java

Why comparison of null `Boolean` variable gives me `NPE` using `==` operator but same operator on null `String` variable do not give `NPE`.
**Snippet:**

```
public static Boolean disableDownloadOnShareURL = null; 
public static String hi= null;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        if(disableDownloadOnShareURL == true)
            System.out.println("Boolean Comparison True");
        else
            System.out.println("Boolean Comparison False");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception got while comparing Boolean values");
    }

    try
    {
        if(hi == "true")
            System.out.println("String Comparison True");
        else
            System.out.println("String Comparison False");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception got while comparing String values");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Null Pointer Exception got while comparing Boolean values
String Comparison False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005286/check-if-null-boolean-is-true-results-in-exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the case of Booleans comparing with booleans the VM tries to unbox the variable (i.e. trying to make a boolean out a Boolean). If this object is null, you get a NPE. On a String nothing like is done, so you don't get a NPE.